# Centos: How to get my new office IP address to allow me SSH access into my virtual CentOS server?

Tags: centos

I have a virtual Centos server setup on a Centos server. I need to connect in via SSH from a remote Windows machine via Putty.

This was working up until recently we changed internet connections and received a new static IP address.

I've tried editing my httpd config files, qos.conf, iptables to allow firewall access, sshd_config, ssh_configcd, hosts.allow, hosts.deny, and a few other files that I could think of checking.

Is there a specific file I should be checking or looking for to be able to get SSH working again? I do believe the old IP address was added to a file somewhere that allowed us access.

**UPDATE**: Using SSH with Putty to attempt to log-in I was getting Error Connection Timed Out. By going through some of the files in the /etc/ folder I came across a folder called CSF which contains some IP addresses in the csf.allow. I went ahead and added our new IP address and restarted CSF. After this, I now get the error: Connection refused.

**UPDATE 2**: I decided to run a debug on SSHD and I am now getting the following message:

```
Cannot bind to port 22 on [my new static ip]
Bind to port 22 on [my new static ip] failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Comment: Can you post the command and error?

Comment: When you got your new connection, did your router hardware change?  If so, did you forward port 22 to your server (or otherwise allowing incoming ssh)?

Comment: I added an update with some more information. I'm thinking this is due to csf.

Comment: What device actually answers the new static IP address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I believe the virtual server itself. I'm not sure though, I am attempting to SSH via the domain name and ip address and both are giving me the same message

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this resolved. I looked inside of the SSHD config file and there was some ListenAddress: open. I commented those out and restarted SSHD. This then allowed everything to start, stop, and reload without a failed message.

I can now SSH in from my office.